# Constraining type of instance using a method result

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing

In a large framework I have a python class, which uses a convenience method to check its category. I would like that to properly type-hint that, such that IDEs could consider that. Is there a way to type hint that, and if so, how?

Here my example code to clarify the problem.

The defined classes:

```py
from abc import ABC
from enum import Enum

class MyCategories(Enum):
    A = "A"
    B = "B"


class SomeBaseClass(ABC):

    def __init__(self, category: MyCategories):
        self.category = category
    
    @property
    def is_a(self): # -> if True, self is MyClassA
        return self.category == MyCategories.A

    @property
    def is_b(self): # -> if True, self is MyClassB
        return self.category == MyCategories.B


class MyClassA(SomeBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(category=MyCategories.A)
    
    def special_a_method(self):
        print("a")

class MyClassB(SomeBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(category=MyCategories.B)

    def special_b_method(self):
        print("b")
```

Now to the use case, where I'd like the typing to understand the behavior:

```py
some_list: list[SomeBaseClass] = [MyClassA(), MyClassB()]


for my_obj in some_list:
    if my_obj.is_a:
        my_obj.special_a_method()  # here
    if my_obj.is_b:
        my_obj.special_b_method()  # and here, the typing should be fixed
```

When I am using VSCode (with pylance typing), it correctly identifies the issue

```
Cannot access member "special_a_method" for type "SomeBaseClass"
  Member "special_a_method" is unknown
```

Of course the code works and correctly prints out `a` and `b`.

Remarks:

- I am aware that this does not conform to all [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles, e.g. the `__init__` of the child class has different parameters, or the fact the the base class strongly couples with the derived classes. But this is what we have to work with now.
- Using python 3.10

Comment: You cannot `TypeGuard` instance itself by its method. If you don't mind extra verbosity to satisfy type checker, here's what you can do: [playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=83e3572adce5862808eedd8fcc60f3ff). LMK if it works for you, I'll write a more detailed answer if yes.